# Show another controller after post request on SWIFT using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login controller. After you type in your username and password, click Sign-In button. In the sign-in button. this is the code from sign in where I called the post and I already defined webservicecontroller in the log in controller.

```
let urlString = "http://app.sampleurl.com:3000/sign-up"
                    let params = ["User[username]":txtUsername.text, "User[email]":txtEmail.text, "User[password]":txtPassword.text]
                    webService.postRequestFromUrl(urlString, withDictionary: params, withHeader: false)
               if let isSuccess = webService.response["success"] as? Bool{
                    if (isSuccess){
                        if let getData = webService.response["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                            if let token = getData["token"] as? NSDictionary{
                                if let passport = token["passport"] as? String{
                                    defaults.setValue(passport, forKey: "token")
                                }
                            }
                            if let user = getData["user"] as? NSDictionary{
                                if let username = user["username"] as? String{
                                    defaults.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
                                }
                                if let email = user["email"] as? String{
                                    defaults.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                                }
                                if let score = user["score"] as? Int{
                                    defaults.setValue(score, forKey: "score")
                                }
                            }
                            let sidePanel = JASidePanelController()
                            let dashController = DashboardController()
                            let menuController = MenuViewController()
                            let navDashController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashController)
                            sidePanel.centerPanel = navDashController
                            sidePanel.leftPanel = menuController
                            self.presentViewController(sidePanel, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    else{
                        println("error on sign-up")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is the code in webserviceController

```
var response: NSDictionary = [:]
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
func postRequestFromUrl(urlString: String, withDictionary parameters:[NSObject:AnyObject], withHeader: BooleanType){
   let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    NSLog("Request Parameters: %@", parameters);
         manager.POST(urlString, parameters: parameters, success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
            if let responseData = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
                self.response = responseData
            }
            }, failure: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            })
}
```

the problem is that when the sign-in button is clicked, the isSuccess is still false since the request have not finished yet and when the request arrives and the isSuccess if finally true it's too late due to being already executed. I've been looking for the solution since yesterday. I'm not allowed to add a post request in the login controller because it will make the WebServiceController useless and I really have to use it as instructed by my mentor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `postRequestFromUrl` function calls the **asynchronous** AFNetworking function `POST`. The method returns before the request has completed.

You would need to provide a callback block to your `postRequestFromUrl` function that would be called when the `success` or `failure` blocks are called from AFNetworking.

```
let urlString = "http://app.sampleurl.com:3000/sign-up"
let params = ["User[username]":txtUsername.text, "User[email]":txtEmail.text, "User[password]":txtPassword.text]

// The trailing block will be invoked when the response has been received.
// Note that this method will still return BEFORE the response has been received.
webService.postRequestFromUrl(urlString, withDictionary: params, withHeader: false) { success in
    if (success) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the updated `postRequestFromUrl`

```
func postRequestFromUrl(urlString: String, withDictionary parameters:[NSObject:AnyObject], withHeader: BooleanType, callback: (success: Bool) -> ()) {

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    NSLog("Request Parameters: %@", parameters);
    manager.POST(urlString, parameters: parameters, success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!)in
        println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        if let responseData = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
            self.response = responseData

            // Invoke the supplied callback block to inform the caller that the request finished
            callback(true)
        }
        }, failure: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

            // Invoke the supplied callback block to inform the caller that the request finished
            callback(false)
        })

}
```

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is already in the web service controller. It does what is in the block. I'm looking for something that would maybe detect when the request is done so that I could make another controller show or something that will make the `if(isSuccess)` block to execute only when the request is done.

Comment: What happens in the `success` (or `failure`) block happens **after** `postRequestFromUrl` has returned. So in order for your login controller to know that the response has finished it will need a callback. This is what I have described. I'll update the answer with some sample code, maybe that will make it more clear.

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot live up to your expectation but I'm new with swift (like only a month since I started learning). I searched for the things you mentioned that would solve my problem but I can't seem to be getting still what you mean. I'm sorry. T.T

Comment: That's fine, we all have to start somewhere. Have you tried using the code I have supplied?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I cannot express it more using text but I can assure you that what I feel now is beyond happiness. I hope you can help more people and I hope my question will be useful for many.